# Stringizing ObjectiveC Strings at runtime

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to stringize an Objective C string at runtime.

Is it possible to use the stringizing operator to do this? I realize it's a preprocessed macro, but could I combine it with a function that returned a char*?

This is what I'd like to do is..

```
#define strthis(x) #x
char *itsstringized = strthis([@"my string" UTF8String]);
printf("%s", itsstringized);
```

Result:

`"my string"`

not

`my string`

Comment: kindly give what will be your input? how you want to give input and how you wish to get the value back?

Comment: See sample (non-working) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

Pass a string to a method and it will return the string enclosed in a quotes.

```
-(NSString *)stringizedString(NSString *)str{
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", str];
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to use the UTF8 of the string. I'll modify this with.. - (const char *)stringizedUTF8StringFromString:(NSString *)str{ return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", str] UTF8String];

Answer (score 1):

You sure can! Try this macro out:

```
#define QUOTEIFY(input) @("\"" #input "\"")
#define QUOTEIFY_STRING(input) @("\"" input "\"")
```

Usage:

```
NSLog(QUOTEIFY(Hello World!)); // notice I didn't quote what's inside the brackets.
// or, if you prefer:
NSLog(QUOTEIFY_STRING("Hello, World!"));
```